# Cannot install Haven R

Tags: python, r, r-haven

I tried using both install.packages("tidyverse") and install.packages("haven"). However, it says -bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('

After running brew doctor, I received this message:
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8-config

Can someone please help me with solving this issue please? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, it seems like bash error rather than R. Do you run the install commands inside R (i.e. R console, RGui, RStudio)?

Comment: Hi! I'm new to programming so I'm not sure what installing commands inside R means. Would you mind explaining? Sorry for the hassle

Comment: As I understand it, you need to install tidyverse and haven packages to R? So you need to open R: either try to type just `R` in your terminal and enter - and then install the packages. Or install [RStudio](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download) and start that. Then run your install commands like `install.packages("haven")` inside RStudio.

Comment: So I've downloaded Rstudio and have tried running the install.packages("tidyverse")  but this message popped up:

Comment: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/HIShape.h:22:10: fatal error: 
      'QD/Quickdraw.h' file not found
#include <QD/Quickdraw.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [src/unix/libuv_la-darwin-proctitle.lo] Error 1
make: *** [libuv/.libs/libuv.a] Error 2

Comment: Oh, that's weird. Try running this in RStudio: `install.packages("tidyverse", type = "binary", dependencies = TRUE)` and let me know, please.

Comment: didn't work. I got this: Error in install.packages("tidyverse", type = "binary", dependencies = TRUE) : 
  type 'binary' is not supported on this platform